# How to Include Source File in Column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of 50+ Excel files that I loop through and consolidate into one dataframe.  However, I need to know the source of the data, since the data will repeat across these files.

Each file name is the date of the report.  Since this data is time series data, I need to pull this date into the dataframe to do further manipulations.

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r"path"
extension = 'xls*'
os.chdir(path)
files = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))
files_df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(fp, usecols=[0,15], header=None) for fp in files], ignore_index=True)
```

I get the expected dataframe.  I just do not know how to include the source file name as a third column.  I thought there was an argument to do this in pd.read_excel(), but I couldn't find it.

For example, I have a list of the following files:

02-2019.xlsx

03-2011.xls

04-2014.xls

etc

I want to include those file names next to the data that comes from that file in the combined dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the `keys=` parameter in `pd.concat()`?

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r"path"
extension = 'xls*'
os.chdir(path)
files = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))

# remove ignore_index=True otherwise keys parameter won't work
files_df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(fp, usecols=[0,15], header=None) for fp in files], keys=[f"{fp.split('.')[0]}" for fp in files])
```

You can then `reset_index()` and convert `to_datetime()`

```
fp.reset_index(inplace=True)

fp['index'] = pd.to_datetime(fp['index'])
```

Comment: Hello!  I think you are very close.  I don't think it works with ignore_index=True.  When I comment that out, then I get what you described.  Does this sound right to you?  Just making sure I didn't screw up something else :)

Comment: @RussW Yes. The `keys` parameter is going to create an index, so passing `ignore_index=True` would result in the keys being ignored. Remove the `ignore_index=True` and you should have what you need.